# Getting goals not specified error when I run Docker image of Karate test

Tags: docker, maven, karate

I am using Karate framework for API automation. my maven and java are configuring fine. I can run tests from cmd with maven test fine but when I create Docker image and try to run it, I get error that goals are not specified. Kindly help!

Comment: you need to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

For the Docker you can create 2 files:

1. Dockerfile

```
    FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
    
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app
    
    COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
    COPY ./src/test/java /usr/src/app/src/test/java
```

2. docker-compose.yml

```
   version: "3.8"
   services: 
   karate-tests:
       image: karate-tests
       build: 
           context: .
           dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
       volumes: 
           - ./target:/usr/src/app/target
           - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
       command: mvn test
```

`command: mvn test` - specify the command want you want to use for running tests.